# Have created a react app (using npx create-react-app) which is getting crash on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have created a react app(by npx create-react-app)  and I am fetching api data (of user's) using  axios and then rendering the data on component(UsersList.js) then on click of a particular user it's navigate to UserHomePage.js( with user details). On refresh of the UserHome page the app is crashing with an error message ( Cannot read property of undefined).
Main.js is root for all components.

gitHub Link:  https://github.com/ajitkrsingh0786/users-profile-react-app 
Netlify Link: https://ajit-users-profile-react-app.netlify.app/

My codes..

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Main from './components/Main';
import { HashRouter, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
 
 
function App() {
   
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Main />
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import UsersList from './UsersList';
import UserHomePage from './UserHomePage';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';


class Main extends  Component{
    constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {
               users: [],
               
           }
    }


        componentDidMount(){
        Axios.get('https://panorbit.in/api/users.json')            
             .then( res => {
                 console.log(res)
                 this.setState(
                     {
                         
                         users: res.data.users,
                     }
                 )
             })
    }
      
    render(){

        const UserWithId = ({match}) => {
            return(
                <UserHomePage user={this.state.users.filter((user) => user.id === parseInt(match.params.userId,10))[0]} />
            );
          };
     
          
        return (
            <div>
             <Switch>
              <Route path='/userList' component={ () =><UsersList users={this.state.users}/>} />
              <Route exact path='/userHomePage' component={UserHomePage} />
              <Route path='/userHomePage/:userId'  component={UserWithId}/>
              <Redirect to="/userList"/>
          </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

UsersList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardHeader,
    CardTitle, Container} from 'reactstrap';
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
 
  function UsersList(props){
         console.log("Ajit");
         console.log(props)
          

      return(
               <Container className="users-list-container">
                <div className="col-5">
                <Card className="users-list-card">
                    <CardHeader>
                        <h4>Users List</h4>
                    </CardHeader>
                <CardBody className="card-body" >
                <ul className="users-list">
                    {
                        props.users.map( user => {
                            return(
                            <Link to={`/userHomePage/${user.id}`} key={user.id}>
                            <li key={user.id}>
                               <div className="user-image user-row">
                                   <img src={user.profilepicture} alt="img" className="user- 
                                    image"/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="user-row">
                                     {user.name}
                                </div>
                                
                                </li>
                                </Link>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
                </CardBody>
                </Card>
                </div>
                </Container>
      )
  }

  export default UsersList;
```

UserHomePage.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
 
  function UserHomePage( props ){

    const history = useHistory();
  console.log("history");
  console.log(history);
  console.log("history");
      return(
          <div  className="home-page">
              <div className="nav-bar">
                  <ul className="ul-nav-bar">
                    <li className="li-nav-bar"> <h4>Profile</h4> </li>
                    <li className="li-nav-bar"> <h4>Posts</h4>  </li>
                    <li className="li-nav-bar"> <h4>Gallery</h4></li>
                    <li className="li-nav-bar">  <h4>ToDo</h4>  </li>                  
                  </ul>                                      
              </div>
              <div  className="home-page-body">
                  <div className="row-1">
                       <h4 className="row-1">Users Home page</h4>
                         <div className="user-image user-row">
                                   <img src={props.user.profilepicture} alt="img" 
                                     className="user-image"/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="user-row">
                                     {props.user.name}
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row-2">
               
               <img src={props.user.profilepicture} alt="user image" />
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      )
  }

  export default UserHomePage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you land on the first page `/userlist` then the API call for the data in componentdidmount gives you the data. And then you redirect to the `/userHomePage/:userId` page on clicking of particular user link from userlist page. Now as the data for this component that you created on render was already there from component did mount

```
const UserWithId = ({
    match
}) => {
    return ( <
        UserHomePage user = {
            this.state.users.filter((user) => user.id === parseInt(match.params.userId, 10))[0]
        }
        />
    );
};
```

but when you refresh the page `/userHomePage/:userId`, then the render for Main.js is called first, when the state is empty and hence the filter you used in above definition in that render will give you undefined object. So in the component `UserHomePage` the undefined is creating the error, and the componentDidMount method will not be called.
The solution of this might me using null checks in `UserHomePage`
So the code for UserHomePage will be

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';
 
  function UserHomePage( props ){
      return(
          <div  className="home-page">
              <div className="nav-bar">
                  <ul className="ul-nav-bar">
                    <li className="li-nav-bar"><h4>Profile</h4></li>
                    <li className="li-nav-bar"><h4>Posts</h4></li>
                    <li className="li-nav-bar"><h4>Gallery</h4></li>
                    <li className="li-nav-bar"><h4>ToDo</h4></li>                  
                  </ul>                                      
              </div>
              <div  className="home-page-body">
                  <div className="row-1">
                       <h4 className="row-1">Users Home page</h4>
                        <div className="user-image user-row">
                                   <img src={props.user && props.user.profilepicture} alt="img" className="user-image"/>
                                </div>

                                <div className="user-row">
                                     {props.user && props.user.name}
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="row-2">
               <img src={props.user && props.user.profilepicture} alt="user image" />
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      )
  }

  export default UserHomePage;
```

So that initially it will render empty data and then after componentDidMount it will print the actual filtered user data